# Google Maps Support Fragment not updating Polygon reliable

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got a `SupportMapFragment` which contains a bunch of overlays (`Polygons`, `Polylines`, `Markers`.

**What I want to do**

The `Polygons` kind of represents a user interacable area, therefore I'd like to highlight them (change the fill color) whenever they are clicked. Because only one `Polygon` shell be shown as selected, the further selected `Polygon` shell get the default color.

**This is what I do:**

```
  private synchronized void selectPolygon(Polygon polygon) {
    if (polygon != null && selectedPolygon != polygon) {
       selectedPolygon.setFillColor(COLOR_DEFAULT);
    }
    if (polygon != null)
       polygon.setFillColor(COLOR_SELECTED);
    selectedPolygon = polygon;
    mapFragment.getView().invalidate(); // added this because I was hoping this does the trick
  }
```

**What actually happens**

Changing or switching the fill colors works for about 2 or 3 times in a row. After that, the Polygon color won't change. The fill color itself is set correctly but the map won't get updated. If I zoom in our out (which seems to force a redraw or something similar) the correct polygon colors will be shown.

I guess I need some kind of `invalidate()` for the `SupportMapFragment` but I couldn't find something like that in the documenation. Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 1):

the proper way to do this with consistency would be to remove and re-add the polygon on the map with the color changes

Comment: I'm using this as a workaround for now, but I can't believe that this is the suggested behavior of the GoogleMaps Fragment.  .